# ConTeXt: How to dissociate number from partlabel in setuphead

Tags: sectioning, context

I would like to change `numberstyle` or `{front|body|back|appendix}partlabel` style in `\setuphead`, however it seems they are somehow associated:

```
\setuplabeltext[en][chapter={Chapter~}]

\setuphead[chapter][bodypartlabel=chapter]


\starttext
\chapter{A chapter}
\stoptext
```

[image]

```
\setuplabeltext[en][chapter={Chapter~}]

\setuphead[chapter][bodypartlabel=chapter,
                    numbercolor=red]


\starttext
\chapter{A chapter}
\stoptext
```

[image]

How can I dissociate them ? Or at least modify one without modifying the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `deepnumbercommand` let you pass a command so it only affects the number and not labels:

```
\setuplabeltext[en][chapter=Chapter~]

\setuphead[chapter][bodypartlabel=chapter,
deepnumbercommand={\color[red]}]


\starttext
\chapter{A chapter}
\stoptext
```